# How to set Dynamic transport for Nestjs-modules/mailer

Tags: nestjs, node-modules, nodemailer

I am working on nestjs-modules/mailer, in my requirements, I have two options to send emails, the first option is using  SMTP transport and the second one is using AWS SES.

My question is how to implement this instead of using transport in Module and setting transport in sendMail({}) function.

email.module.ts

```
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { join } from 'path';
import { EmailService } from './email.service';
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SES } from 'aws-sdk';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        transport:{
          SES: new SES({
            accessKeyId:config.get('S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            secretAccessKey:config.get('S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            region:config.get('S3_REGION')
          })
        },

        defaults: {
          from: `"No Reply" <${config.get('SMTP_MAIL_FROM')}>`,
        },
        template: {
          dir: join(__dirname, 'templates'),
          adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [EmailService],
  exports: [EmailService],
})
export class EmailModule {}
```

email.service.ts

```
import { MailerService } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Payload } from './entities/payload.entity';
import { createTransport } from "nodemailer";
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class EmailService {
  constructor(private readonly mailerService: MailerService, _configService: ConfigService) {}

  async SESEmail(context: any): Promise<void> {
    
    return await this.mailerService.sendMail({
      to: context.toEmail,
      subject: `Gentle Reminder ${context.taskName}`,
      template: './welcome',
      context: {
        context
      },
    });
  }
```

I need to set transport from my service instead of defining it in the module

Comment: maybe https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/issues/371

Answer (score 1):

hopefully you have solve this issue.for whose who have similar use case.
the mailer service provided by nest js provide a function called

```
   ` mailerService.addTransporter(transportName: string,{
...dynamicConfig})`
```

- each you add a transport with same name it override the existing transport
- when you want to send mail call the function

`mailerService.sendMail({ transportName, ...Params })`

hopefully it can help someone